# T-SQL - Remove everything before and after in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please assist me with the SQL query shown below.

This is the error I get:

> System.Exception: TransformerException ---> Library.Utilities.TransformerException: Transformer transforming [00000000000**85153227**:documentId] using [4:transformId] with time remaining [00:00:54.4517645:TimeSpan] output document is [0000000000085153231:documentId] ---> and so on...

I'm training to retrieve this value 85153227 only.

Please assist

```
SELECT  
    SUBSTRING(message, 0, CHARINDEX('System.Exception', message)) + ' ' +  
    CASE          
       WHEN CHARINDEX('Transformer transforming [', message) > 0
          THEN SUBSTRING(message, CHARINDEX('[',message), LEN(message)-CHARINDEX('[', message)) 
          ELSE '' 
    END
FROM
    dbo.Documents
```

Thank you

Comment: What determines the string you want to parse? Everything after the zeros and before the colon character?

Comment: Is the "full output string" the result of your current query, or the full value of the `message` column?

Comment: Hi Jasob, exactly!,- everything after zeros and before the colon.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ AS VARCHAR(MAX)= 
'System.Exception: TransformerException ---> Library.Utilities.TransformerException: Transformer transforming [0000000000085153227:documentId] using [4:transformId] with time remaining [00:00:54.4517645:TimeSpan] output document is [0000000000085153231:documentId]'

SELECT 
CAST(
SUBSTRING(@,
    CHARINDEX('Transformer transforming [',@,0) + LEN('Transformer transforming [')
,   CHARINDEX(':documentId]',@,0) - ( CHARINDEX('Transformer transforming [',@,0) + LEN('Transformer transforming [') ))
AS BIGINT)
```

--OUTPUT

```
--------------------
85153227

(1 row affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine an exact response to this because you did not identify if the exception is always structured the same. With what is provided, this is what I would do.

1. Removing the leading string of characters with `STUFF`; `STUFF([Message], 1, CHARINDEX(N'Transformer transforming [', [Message]) + 25, N'')`
2. Then assuming that the string of characters with the number is 19 characters long, I then do a `SUBSTRING` to find the first non-zero character. `SUBSTRING({field}, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', {field} + '.'), LEN({field}))` substituting step 1 into this string for `{field}` (I tried to simplify the code here).

Here is the SQL statement showing this.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
SELECT CAST('System.Exception: TransformerException ---> Library.Utilities.TransformerException: Transformer transforming [0000000000085153227:documentId] using [4:transformId] with time remaining [00:00:54.4517645:TimeSpan] output document is [0000000000085153231:documentId] ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    AS [Message]
    INTO #t

SELECT *,
    STUFF([Message], 1, CHARINDEX(N'Transformer transforming [', [Message]) + 25, N'') AS BeginningCharactersStripped,
    SUBSTRING(LEFT(STUFF([Message], 1, CHARINDEX(N'Transformer transforming [', [Message]) + 25, N''), 19), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', LEFT(STUFF([Message], 1, CHARINDEX(N'Transformer transforming [', [Message]) + 25, N''), 19) + '.'), LEN(LEFT(STUFF([Message], 1, CHARINDEX(N'Transformer transforming [', [Message]) + 25, N''), 19)))
        AS Number
FROM #t
WHERE [Message] like N'%Transformer transforming [[]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided I modified your query a bit to get the output you want.  You may need to adjust depending on your data.

```
SELECT  substring(message,0,charindex('System.Exception',message)) + ' ' + 
CASE          WHEN charindex('Transformer transforming [',message) > 0
          THEN Convert(Varchar(8000), Convert(BigInt, Substring(message,charindex('[',message) + 1, charindex(':documentid]',message)-(CharIndex('[',message)+1)))) ELSE '' END
FROM dbo.Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with MsgWithZeroesTbl as 
(SELECT  'System.Exception ' + 
        CASE      
            WHEN charindex('Transformer transforming [',message) >= 0
            THEN substring(message,charindex('[',message) + 1, charindex(':',message, charindex('[',message))- (charindex('[',message) + 1)) ELSE '' 
        END as MsgWithZeros
        FROM dbo.Documents )
Select substring(MsgWithZeros, patindex('%[^0]%',MsgWithZeros), 10) from MsgWithZeroesTbl
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(8000) = 
'System.Exception: TransformerException ---> Library.Utilities.TransformerException: Transformer transforming [0000000000085153227:documentId] using [4:transformId] with time remaining [00:00:54.4517645:TimeSpan] output document is [0000000000085153231:documentId] --->'

SELECT cast(substring(@string, p1.p, p2.p-p1.p) as bigint)
FROM (VALUES (patindex('%[0-9]%', @string))) p1(p)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (charindex(':', @string, p1.p+1))) p2(p);
```

Output:

```
85153227
```